# Adding color to table columns with alignment

Tags: tables, color, vertical-alignment

I am trying to add color to certain columns in a table for highlighting purposes. In said columns, I have positioned the data presented to be aligned by the decimal point. However, when adding color to these columns, this alignment is disregarded. Any thoughts about how to restore this alignment? I have provided MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.8pt}

\begin{document} 
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l| g@{,}g r@{.}l g@{,}g r@{.}l}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}x}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}y}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}w}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}z}\\
\hline
variable 1 &-0&54&&&1&64&&\\
variable 2&&&&&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your problem correctly, but here is how I would do it.

First some explanations ahead:

- `dcolumn` is a package that provides you with columns for aligning decimal numbers at a given seperator, e.g. I define in the following two new columntypes using `D{.}{.}{2}`, the first `.` is your input and the second the output seperator, the `2` sets alignment to two decimal places
- `\mc` is short for a centered multicolumn
- `a` and `b` are white and gray dcolumns
- `\rowcolor{LightCyan}` sets the color for the entire row, so you don't have do define it for every single cell

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}D{.}{.}{2}}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}D{.}{.}{2}}

\begin{document} 


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l | a | b | a | b}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\mc{1}{}  & \mc{1}{x} & \mc{1}{y} & \mc{1}{w} & \mc{1}{z} \\
\hline
variable 1 & -0.54 & & 1.64 &  \\
variable 2 &       & &      &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]